# Ubuntu seems to be unable to detect hardware

Tags: 14.04, unity, sound, compiz, shutdown

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with the Unity desktop on a Lenovo Thinkpad T440p. I have started to see some major problems occur without any obvious reason.

I first noticed that my computer was running slow. I used top and saw that the compiz process was using about 200% CPU.

I then noticed that my sound wouldn't work, with the only output device being listed being "Dummy Output".

I tried to restart my computer using the desktop buttons, but nothing happened. I got the computer to begin doing a shutdown using sudo shutdown now, and it made some progress towards shutting down, but I eventually needed to help it by pressing the hardware power button.

After trying some things to fix the above problems, I got an error saying that I am out of disk space. My computer reports only 49 GB of disk space. I should have well over 200.

Edit: I also get an error whenever I plug in a flash drive that says "Unable to mount X.X GB Volume. Not authorized to perform operation." Regardless of which flash drive I plug in. The flash drives work on other computers.

Edit2: Some more problems I have just noticed, using the Unity search, I cannot find any of my applications. When I try to start libre office from the command line, I get this error:

> dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file '/home/username/.cache/dconf/user': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.

and if I try to run as sudo:

> Unable to copy the user's Xauthorization file.

It seems to me that Ubuntu is having some trouble detecting and interacting with my hardware. Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.